# How can I prevent from extracting APK of my application using other application?

Tags: android, android-lvl

I am developing a non-free android application. How can I prevent others from sharing apk to other users, like if I am using share-it or Xender we can share a apk which is installed in our application to others. Is there any way to prevent our application from sharing the apk?

Please add your thoughts.

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent it from being downloaded or shared. It's a problem each app faces, even well-known apps apk are available easily over internet, all you need is to search for it :)

What you can do is **restrict User** to use it, if he has not purchased it.
Assuming this app will be on Google Play, & **what you need is** [Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html)

Using this you can identify user has rights to use this app or not.
if the user has not purchased it, he will not be able to use your app.

If this app is not going to be on Google Play store, you can see respective app store billing library.

Answer (score -1):

Set allowBackup="false" to your application in your androidmanifest file.

Read more about flags - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html